I want to test LSALOGONUSER to do certificate based authentication without the use of smartcard
I have got a reference here. Can anyone tell what is wrong in the code . What all changes would i require if it is not a domain user but a local account not connected to any domain.
I have got another good reference link here but here also what changes would i require if i don't have a smartcard and i will fetch certificates from personal user store
I tried the method but getting some LSALOGIN failed as stated in the thread
In the reference code for a non domain user, I granted the necessary SCTCBPriviledge. After that i populated the Certificate data for LSALOGON as below from the personal certificate store. But the method fails as shown below in the output
    BOOL ConstructAuthCertInfo(const KERB_CERTIFICATE_UNLOCK_LOGON& rkiulIn,LPBYTE* ppbAuthInfo, ULONG* pulAuthInfoLen)  
    {  
       UNICODE_STRING DomainName;  
       UNICODE_STRING UserName;  
       UNICODE_STRING Password;  
       NTSTATUS Status;  
       ULONG_PTR Ptr;  
       ULONG AuthInfoLength;  
       wstring WProvName;  
       DWORD ProvSize = 0;  
       wstring containerName;  
       DWORD contSize = 0;  
       HCRYPTPROV hProv;  
       DWORD dwKeySpec;  
     
       // Fetching the certificate context from the certificate store    
       // and recieving the CSP handle for the user certificate  
       HCERTSTORE      hStoreHandle = NULL;  
       PCCERT_CONTEXT  pCertContext = NULL;  
       LPCTSTR pszStoreName = _T("MY");  
       CERT_CREDENTIAL_INFO certInfo;  
       HCRYPTHASH hHash;  
       BOOL bStatus;  
       DWORD dwHashLen = CERT_HASH_LENGTH;  
       LPWSTR szMarshaledCred = NULL;  
       HANDLE hToken;  
     
       hStoreHandle = CertOpenSystemStore(NULL, pszStoreName);  
     
       if (hStoreHandle)  
       {  
           // Since my certificate store has only one user certificate, tring to retrieve PCERT_CONTEXT for it  
           pCertContext = CertFindCertificateInStore(  
               hStoreHandle,  
               PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING,  
               0,  
               CERT_FIND_ANY,  
               NULL,  
               NULL);  
     
           if (pCertContext)  
           {  
     
               BOOL bFreeHandle;  
     
               // acquire private key container to this certificate      
               if (CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(pCertContext, CRYPT_ACQUIRE_ALLOW_NCRYPT_KEY_FLAG, NULL, &hProv, &dwKeySpec, &bFreeHandle))  
               {  
                   cout << "The private key container handle is accessed.. "<<endl<<"The dwKeySpec Value is: "<<dwKeySpec<<endl;  
                 
     
                   //Fetching the container name where the certificate is stored  
                   if (CryptGetProvParam(hProv, PP_CONTAINER, NULL, &contSize, 0))  
                   {  
                       BYTE* contName = (BYTE*)malloc(contSize);  
                       if (CryptGetProvParam(hProv, PP_CONTAINER, contName, &contSize, 0))  
                       {  
                           containerName = wstring(contName, contName + contSize);  
                           wcout << "The container name is: " << containerName << endl;  
                       }  
                       else  
                       {  
                           cout << "Could not get the container name. Exiting.."<<endl;  
                           return FALSE;  
     
                       }  
                   }  
                   else  
                   {  
                       cout << "Could not get the container size. Exiting.."<<endl;  
                       return FALSE;  
     
                   }  
     
                   //Fetching the CSP name where the certificate is stored  
                   if (CryptGetProvParam(hProv, PP_NAME, NULL, &ProvSize, 0))  
                   {  
                       BYTE* ProvName = (BYTE*)malloc(ProvSize);  
                       if (CryptGetProvParam(hProv, PP_NAME, ProvName, &ProvSize, 0))  
                       {  
                           WProvName = wstring(ProvName, ProvName + ProvSize);  
                           wcout << "The name of the CSP is: " << WProvName << endl;  
                       }  
                       else  
                       {  
                           cout << "The CSP name could not be retrieved. Exiting.." << endl;  
                           return FALSE;  
                       }  
                   }  
                   else  
                   {  
                       cout << "The CSP name size could not be retrieved. Exiting.." << endl;  
                       return FALSE;  
                   }  
     
                }  
               else  
               {  
                   cout << "Could not get the Private Key Container handle. Exiting...";  
                   return FALSE;  
               }  
           }  
           else  
           {  
               cout << "Could not find the user certificate in the Certificate store. Exiting.." << endl;  
               return FALSE;  
           }  
       

According to first reference, for user for non domain user i changed the username and domain but giving this output -:
private key container handle is accessed..
The dwKeySpec Value is: 1
The container name is: te-982a66ce-84d6-49ce-b784-76930d71e80b
The name of the CSP is: Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider
LsaLogonUser failed with error 0x0000052E. SubStatus = 0x000004F0 

I created the x509 certificate using Powershell command :
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My `
     -Subject "CN=testuser" `
     -KeySpec KeyExchange `
     -Provider "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" `
     -KeyLength 2048 `
     -KeyExportPolicy Exportable `
     -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(5)

I installed this certificate on personal user store as well as trusted store as well. But still LSALOGON fails? Why?
